# PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL syntax error with FOREACH loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to learn PL/pgSQL by writing some simple programs. To learn about FOREACH loop, I wrote the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(int[]) RETURNS void AS $$  
DECLARE                                                     
    window INT;                                             
BEGIN                                                       
    FOREACH window IN ARRAY $1                              
    LOOP                                                    
        EXECUTE 'SELECT $1' USING window;                   
    END LOOP;                                               
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;                                        

SELECT test(ARRAY [30,60]);
```

I expect that this code snippet would first print `30` and then `60`. However, I get the following error.

```
psql:loop.sql:11: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 7:         EXECUTE 'SELECT $1' USING window;
                                                ^
psql:loop.sql:13: ERROR:  function test(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT test(ARRAY [30,60]);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
 to add explicit type casts.
```

So the function definition has a syntax error, but I don't understand what the error is and how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function is declared as `returns void` so you can't return anything from it. If you want to return multiple values, you need to use `returns setof integer`

But it has more problems than that.

1. you should give your parameter a name (not an error, but good coding style)
2. to return a value from a function you need to use `return`. To return multiple values (because of `returns setof`) you need to use `return next`
3. there is no need for a dynamic SQL to return a value, you can return the variable directly.
4. Also not not an error, but: `window` is a keyword, I wouldn't use a variable with that name.

Applying all that, your function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(p_input int[]) 
  RETURNS setof integer
as
$$  
DECLARE                                                     
  l_value INT;                                             
BEGIN                                                       
    FOREACH l_value IN ARRAY p_input                             
    LOOP                                                    
        return next l_value;
    END LOOP;                                               
end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

I am not sure if you are aware, but there is already a built-in function which achieves the same thing: `unnest()`.

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I need to get `EXECUTE... USING` to work as well. Do you know what's the issue with `EXECUTE... USING` in my code?

Comment: Update: it's because of the `WINDOW` keyword. It works after I changed the variable name.